# Understanding a proof of Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The Chebyshev's inequality is
$$P(|X-E(X)|>\varepsilon)\leq \frac{\operatorname{Var(X)}}{\varepsilon^2}.$$

I saw a proof which goes like this:

$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var(X)}(X) &= E((X-E(X))^2) \\
&= \sum_{x\in S}(x-E(X))^2\cdot  P(X=x) \\
&\geq \sum_{|x-E(X)|>\varepsilon}(x-E(X))^2\cdot P(X=x) \\
&> \sum_{|x-E(X)|>\varepsilon}\varepsilon^2\cdot P(X=x) \\
&= \varepsilon^2 P(|X-E(X)|>\varepsilon) \\
\end{align}
$$

from which the equation should follow by dividing by $\varepsilon^2$.

What I don't understand here is the 4th step:

$$\sum_{|x-E(X)|>\varepsilon}(x-E(X))^2\cdot P(X=x) 
> \sum_{|x-E(X)|>\varepsilon}\varepsilon^2\cdot P(X=x)
$$

Doen't this imply
$$P(|X-E(X)|>\varepsilon)< \frac{\operatorname{Var(X)}}{\varepsilon^2}$$
rather then
$$P(|X-E(X)|>\varepsilon)\leq \frac{\operatorname{Var(X)}}{\varepsilon^2}.$$

Why is this correct?

Comment: @In a technical sense, it is not incorrect. If I say $5\le 7$, I am not lying.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$P(|X-E(X)|>\varepsilon)< \frac{Var(X)}{\varepsilon^2}$$
is (sometimes) false. For let $X=a$ with probability $1$. The variance of $X$ is $0$, but no probability can be $<0$. But if we assume non-zero variance, your reasoning is correct.

The usual version of the Chebyshev Inequality is
$$P(|X-E(X)|\ge \varepsilon) \le \frac{Var(X)}{\varepsilon^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So this [Wikibooks entry](http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mathematik:_Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie:_DW:_K7:_Die_Chebyshev-Ungleichung) is in general wrong, then? I'm sorry that this is in german. But the proof is in formulas, and they are international (at least I hope so). :-)

Comment: @Aufwind: The Wikibooks entry divides by $\sigma_X$.  This makes sense only when the variance is non-zero. Perhaps that is explicitly mentioned somewhere, though I only see the requirement that the variance is $<\infty$. But $0$ variance is not interesting!

Comment: Actually the German Wikibooks entry says $$P(|X-EX| > \varepsilon) \le \dfrac{\mathrm{Var}(X)}{\varepsilon^2}$$  with a $\le$ rather than $\lt$, so it is true.

Comment: @Henry: Yes, and the OP quoted it correctly. I was just noting that in the entry there is division by the standard deviation, so implicitly at least non-zero is assumed. The  "$\dots$ is (sometimes) false" in my answer refers to the version the OP was thinking about.

Comment: Fine - I was really responding to "So this Wikibooks entry is in general wrong, then?", to which the answer is no.